# How to remove intermediate date-time values between rows based on pass/fail field to obtain first and last pass/failures for each sub-group.

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using MSSMS 2008 R2 on a Win7 Machine. I have this table of data that I pulled after some basic queries:

[image]

Each row represents a pass/failure event. Pass = TPSD and Failure = TFLT; I am trying to obtain deltas between **every** initial TFLT and most recent TPSD (first TPSD after TFLT). My first approach was to enumerate each row entry using the ROW_NUMBER() function doing this which works fine when data are ordered consecutively:

```
WITH ROWS AS 
    (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order BY T.Location, T.BIT_TIME) AS RN 
    FROM #TEMP1 T 
    )
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, R1.BIT_TIME, R2.BIT_TIME)
FROM ROWS R1
JOIN ROWS R2
on R1.RN = R2.RN - 1
AND R1.EventId = 'TFLT'
AND R2.EventId = 'TPSD'
AND R1.Location = R2.Location
```

But after realizing the data set was not structured as I thought, I hit a wall. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Mind you, this is just a sample of the table there are multiple locations/logids and most are structured consecutively i.e. TFLT,TPSD,TFLT,TPSD, etc.. some are not.

-- Stelio K

Comment: try changing ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order BY T.Location, T.BIT_TIME) to ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by T.Location Order BY  T.BIT_TIME)

Comment: select DATEDIFF(SECOND, R1.BIT_TIME, R2.BIT_TIME)
from (
select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by T.Location Order BY  T.BIT_TIME asc) AS RN )x
join (select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by T.Location Order BY  T.BIT_TIME asc) AS RN )y
on x.RN = y.RN 
and x.Location = y.Location
and y.EventId = 'TFLT'
where x.EventId = 'TPSD' and  x.RN = 1

Comment: It would be cool if you could provide a SQL fiddle with what you're trying. Would make it easier for others to play around. http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/54dcc/1 Created one!

Comment: also please post expected result

Answer (score 0):

I fully rewrite my answer. I remembered about useful thing such as `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))` which helps if there is no any id's:

```
;WITH final AS (
SELECT  LogID, 
        [Location], 
        BIT_TIME, 
        EventId, 
        BitId,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order BY (SELECT 1)) AS RN 
FROM TEMP1 T  
)

SELECT  r.BIT_TIME,
        r.EventId,
        r.BIT_TIME1,
        r.EventId1,
        DATEDIFF(SECOND,r.BIT_TIME,r.BIT_TIME1) as Sec
FROM (
    SELECT t.BIT_TIME, 
            t.EventId, 
            CAST(tq.BIT_TIME as datetime) as BIT_TIME1, 
            tq.EventId as EventId1, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.EventId, tq.BIT_TIME ORDER BY t.BIT_TIME ASC) as rn
    FROM final t
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT top 1 *
        FROM final t1 
        WHERE t1.EventId = 'TPSD'and t.BIT_TIME<= t1.BIT_TIME  and t.EventId != t1.EventId and t.RN < t1.RN
        )  as tq
    WHERE t.EventId = 'TFLT'
    ) as r
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY BIT_TIME
```

Output:

```
BIT_TIME                EventId BIT_TIME1               EventId1    Sec
2015-11-29 19:29:42.000 TFLT    2015-11-29 19:30:12.000 TPSD        30
2015-11-29 19:30:33.000 TFLT    2015-11-29 19:30:35.000 TPSD        2
2015-11-29 19:30:36.000 TFLT    2015-11-29 19:30:52.000 TPSD        16
2015-11-29 19:30:53.000 TFLT    2015-11-29 19:30:59.000 TPSD        6
2015-11-29 19:31:02.000 TFLT    2015-11-29 19:31:09.000 TPSD        7
2015-11-29 19:31:53.000 TFLT    2015-11-29 19:31:56.000 TPSD        3
2015-11-29 19:32:13.000 TFLT    2015-11-29 19:32:47.000 TPSD        34
2015-11-29 19:32:48.000 TFLT    2015-11-29 19:32:57.000 TPSD        9
2015-11-29 19:32:57.000 TFLT    2015-11-29 19:33:17.000 TPSD        20
2015-11-29 19:33:18.000 TFLT    2015-11-29 19:33:24.000 TPSD        6
2015-11-29 19:34:13.000 TFLT    2015-11-29 19:35:15.000 TPSD        62
2015-11-29 19:35:16.000 TFLT    2015-11-29 19:35:19.000 TPSD        3
2015-11-29 19:35:22.000 TFLT    2015-11-29 19:35:53.000 TPSD        31
2015-11-29 19:35:54.000 TFLT    NULL                    NULL        NULL
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to provide a concise and elegant answer. Unfortunately, the "query" block you provided produces an error in the outer apply section mainly at t.rn < t1.rn. I am getting an invalid column error message.

Comment: Second part of answer (from the start of script to create tables/cte) is useful, if you have some id column. I created one, just added numbers from 1 to 40 to each row manually.

Comment: I was referring to the Query: part of your answer.

Comment: In the very first query there is only one use to 'rn' - rn=1. Second query is with manually added id and have part t.rn<t1.rn, you cannot use it on your data, if you don't have such field (id). Also as I write in my answer pure ROW_NUMBER() will not help you, because it doesn't guarantee the right order to every row.

Comment: sorry I guess I am just not seeing how you are applying the uniqId  in the block containing t.rn < t1.rn

Comment: The part with cte declaration. Final as (... Row_number over (order by uniqid)... It was just an example. Do you have any column that might guarantee order of the rows right as in your example?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not. The data in my set is exactly as it is in my post.

Comment: Than, you can use first query. Without any guaranteed row order you cannot create result-set you desire.

Comment: As I found out - you can :) I rewrite my answer, please. take a look.